# Отправка в начало страницы при перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, маршрутизация, react-router

Нужно добавить скрипт в React приложение, что бы при перезагрузки страницы откидывало в начало страницы. Так в приложении фиксится много багов с анимированием, приложение сделано на react-router. Помогите сделать, буду благодарен)

Comment: что значит "откидывало в начало страницы"?

Answer (score 0):

Если именно для перезагрузки то вот так:

```
  componentDidMount(prevProps) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
```

Также если перезагрузки не происходит а страница однотипная с меняющимся location то можно привязаться и к нему

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
 }
}
```